# System.NullReferenceException или почему UserManager == null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Всем доброго времени суток, изучая mvc я наткнулся на проблему создания пользователя в БД, все делалось по примеру, но при вводе данных получал вот такое письмо в браузере:

> Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта. Описание:
>   Необработанное исключение при выполнении текущего веб-запроса. Изучите
>   трассировку стека для получения дополнительных сведений о данной
>   ошибке и о вызвавшем ее фрагменте кода.
>
> Сведения об исключении: System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на
>   объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
>
> Ошибка источника:

```
Строка 32:             {
Строка 33:                 ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email};
Строка 34:                 IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
Строка 35:                 if (result.Succeeded)
Строка 36:                 {
```

ошибка в 34 строке. Ниже приведу все что я делал по уроку. 
В папке Models создаю класс с именем ApplicationContext:

```
public class ApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationContext() : base("HomeBDConnectionString") { }

       // public DbSet<RegisterModel> RegisterModels { get; set; }

        public static ApplicationContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationContext();
        }
    }
```

Затем ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ApplicationUser()
        {

        }
    }
```

Затем ApplicationUserManager:

```
 public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
                : base(store)
        {
        }
        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options,
                                                IOwinContext context)
        {
            ApplicationContext db = context.Get<ApplicationContext>();
            ApplicationUserManager manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
            return manager;
        }
    }
```

Далее модель регистрации RegisterModel:

```
public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Пароли не совпадают")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }

    }
```

Далее в папке App_start создаю класс Startup:

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // настраиваем контекст и менеджер
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationContext>(ApplicationContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            });
        }
    }
```

После сам контроллер AccountController:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
        }
        // GET: Account
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email};
                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (string error in result.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
                    }
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

и наконец View Register:

```
@model WebHome.Models.RegisterModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>Регистрация</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div>
        <h4>Регистрация пользователя</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

        <div>
            Электронный адрес
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            Пароль
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            Подтвердить пароль
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PasswordConfirm)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Зарегистрировать" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

web.config:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="HomeBDConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ETHERNETS-ПК\WINCCFLEXEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=HomeBD;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

На скриншоте видно что `UserManager == null`  как вообще он там может быть, когда явно создается экземпляр ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну поставьте breakpoint на строку, в которой происходит исключение, и посмотрите, чему равно значение переменных.

Comment: @Ethernets зачем вы вообще проверяли строку? Прочитайте ответ на приведенный мною вопрос, там все написано.

Comment: @Ethernets и, если вам так интересно, я нашел у вас ошибку прежде чем голосовать за дубликат. И я гарантирую, что по той ссылке вы найдете ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: @Ethernets у вас на скрине отлично видно, что UserManager == null

Comment: @Ethernets прочитайте, пожалуйста, комментарии к этому вопросу с самого начала

Comment: @PavelMayorov Спасибо большое за указание ошибки, я если честно даже не подумал о том что `UserManager == null` Но я не совсем понимаю почему он равен null, я все делал согласно примеру, и целый день перепроверял и искал где я допустил ошибку, поэтому отчаянно создал тему, т.к. ответа я так и не нашел ... Извините за мою вспыльчивость выше, и еще раз большое спасибо

Comment: @Ethernets вам стоит минимизировать вопрос и явно написать в нем "UserManager - null. почему?". И убрать лишний код. Сейчас это написано только на скриншоте и в моем комментарии - а они плохо (вообще никак) индексируются поисковиками.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы найти можно [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064739/owin-not-returning-usermanager) Либо создать обычный MVC проект с типом аутентификации No Authentication. Затем руками добавить нужные сборки для работы: `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.OWIN
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`
Вот такие подарки преподносит VS 2015 Enterprise update 3. Всем спасибо за помощь